# How to build Graphql backend server for existing database?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have just build simple Node.js graphql backend server with Prisma, graphql-yoga, prisma-binding.
And I would like to know if is it possible to create graphql backend server for existing database.
For example, I am deploying Postgresql database in amazon RDB,  and it is not empty database.
In this case,

1. How can I build backend server using Graphql and Node.js for existing database?
2. Graphql backend server building is possible for only newly created database or available for existing database?
3. If I would like to deploy graphql database on specific cloud system(for example godaddy), is it possible and how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We just open-sourced https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine which is ideal for getting started with GraphQL on existing postgres database (even as it is being used in an existing application).
2. You can build your own GraphQL servers to speak to any kind of backend, be it database, a REST API or another GraphQL service. Here's a perfect example/tutorial of doing this:Build a GraphQL gateway for MongoDB, SQL and REST: https://blog.apollographql.com/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035
3. Different hosting providers will support different ways of deployment and their documentation should probably be sufficient. If you a have a specific problem and have tried something out that doesn't work, SO can help.